call/cc mutable environment storage
I have the following Scheme program:
(define sg-pair (let ()
                  (define x #f)
                  (cons
                   (call/cc (lambda (c)
                              (set! x c)))
                   x)))

(display sg-pair)
(display "\n")

(if (eq? (car sg-pair) (void))
    (let ()
      ((cdr sg-pair) "first")))

(if (string? (car sg-pair))
    (let ()
      ((cdr sg-pair) 2)))

This prints the following:
(#!void . #<procedure #2>)
(first . #<procedure #2>)
(2 . #<procedure #2>)

My current understanding of how this pair would be constructed is:

The continuation (c) is created upon invocation of call/cc. At this time, x is #f, and has yet to be evaluated as the second argument of cons.
During the execution of the lambda passed to call/cc, x is set to a non-false (continuation) value.
call/cc returns naturally, and returns nothing (#!void), and x is retrieved from the prior set call.
When the continuation is later called as retrieved via cdr, I would expect for the map of x -> #f, known when the continuation was created, to be restored. Then, because the lambda body of call/cc is not run a second time, x would remain false.
x would be evaluated after the call/cc, this time to #f, resulting in the second display's cdr being different, and the second call of the cdr failing.

However, what really happens is that the prior value of x is remembered when the continuation is re-entered. Why, and how? What mechanism does Scheme actually use to remember environments?

You shouldn't assume that order of evaluation of function arguments is left to right; the Scheme standards don't specify the order. Unless you're just interested in a particular implementation that does document its behavior, of course.

I would expect for the map of x -> #f, known when the continuation was created, to be restored. No? Variables don't have their values changed when you call the continuation. Pretty sure there's other questions about this, but my searches have had dismal results lately when I want to find a specific one.

This question is similar to: Environment not part of a continuation?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


"I would expect for the map of x -> #f, known when the continuation was created, to be restored"

No. Nothing is being restored. x is a binding, local to that let form. It has value. Whatever value it has, is its value. No prior values are remembered, only its current value is maintained, sitting in that place in memory to which the binding points.
Whatever the state of memory is, is not changed. Continuations are only about control flow.
We re-enter same point in code, under same (lexical) bindings. But this does not affect the values those bindings hold. We just get access to those bindings, and - thus - their  values, whatever these bindings' values are at the moment.
Calling the continuation ((cdr sg-pair) value) is equivalent to
(set! sg-pair (cons value x))

but x is the same hidden local binding x. Its value has not changed. It was stored in (cdr sg-pair). Thus each call ((cdr sg-pair) value) is equivalent to
(set! sg-pair (cons value (cdr sg-pair)))

NB. As Shawn points out in a comment, this code only works as intended provided (cons A B) evaluates A before B.
